# PyQt4 or PyQt5 from framebuffer without X server

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqt5, raspberry-pi3, framebuffer

I'm trying to run a PyQt gui application from console on a Raspberry Pi 3.
Withough X11 server.

I tried `xvfb-run python test.py` but it did not work.

In the case of PyQt4, it outputs 
"python: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :99."
When I terminate the process.

In the case of PyQt5, it outputs
"libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to create any config
Cant find EGLConfig, returning null config
Unable to find an X11 visual which matches EGL config 0
Could not initialize OpenGL for RasterGLSurface, reverting to RasterSurface.
Unsupported screen depth: 8"

and then throws this when I kill the process
"The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?"

I'm running raspian jessie

Any idea how to get this working ?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not @jars121
Some suggested buying a Qt for embedded systems license and compile PyQt using that version of Qt

Comment: Thanks Zeyad, that's the realisation I've come to as well. Unfortunately the build instructions for both cross-compiling and natively compiling Qt for the RPi are lacking, but I'll persevere.